# draw bitmap over another bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

i need to draw a bitmap over another bitmap like the image below in java android

[image]

this is my code

```
    private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
    return bmOverlay;
  }
```

how can I determine where to draw Bitmap2 (Coordinates for the start point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the pictures, you want it centered?  Then the answer is

```
x= (bitmap1.getWidth()- bitmap2.getWidth)/2
y= (bitmap1.getHeight()- bitmap2.getHeight)/2
```

Basically, figure out the extra space in bitmap1 over bitmap 2, and cut it in half.

Comment: where shall i add this insert this code snippet?